# Separate a powerpoint presentation into a set of slides using python

Tags: python, powerpoint

I have .ppt files containing presentations and I need to split a single .ppt file into the slides that it is made of and to store each slide as an image. Any way of achieving this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python has a powerpoint library.

Comment: That python library 'python-pptx' cannot do any of the things the user mentioned, it cannot split pptxs, merge or convert to images.

Answer (score 0):

With [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you can easy save each presentation slide to an image. The following code example shows you how to do this:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides
import aspose.pydrawing as draw

with slides.Presentation("example.ppt") as presentation:

    for slide_index, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):

        # Convert the current slide to an image at 100% scale.
        slide_image = slide.get_thumbnail(1, 1)

        # Save the slide image to a PNG file.
        image_path = "slide_{}.png".format(slide_index + 1)
        slide_image.save(image_path, draw.imaging.ImageFormat.png)
```

This is a paid library, but you can get a temporary license or use a trial mode to evaluate all features for managing presentations. You can see the conversion results without any code by using [Online PowerPoint Converter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/conversion). It is based on this library.

Alternatively, you can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/). The code example below shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```py
import asposeslidescloud

from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi
from asposeslidescloud.models import *

slides_api = SlidesApi(None, "my_client_id", "my_client_secret")

with open("example.ppt", "rb") as file_stream:

    # Convert all presentation slides to PNG images at 100% scale.
    result_path = slides_api.convert(file_stream, SlideExportFormat.PNG)

    print("A ZIP file with slide images was saved to " + result_path)
```

This is also a paid product based on REST, but you can make 150 free API calls per month for managing presentations. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose and we will be glad to answer your questions of this products on [Aspose.Slides forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/).